# Horizontal Recycler View with Videos and Text

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I have a Horizontal Recycler View with a Thumbnail Image and a Text. On Clicking of Thumbnail image, the respective video should be played. I'm able to show the image and text and now I got stucked with further proceeding  with playing videos.Any help would be much appreciated.

**Main Activity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView horizontal_recycler_view;
private ArrayList<String> horizontalList;
private HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    horizontal_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_recycler_view);

    horizontalList = new ArrayList<>();
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 1");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 2");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 3");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 4");
    horizontalList.add("horizontal 5");

    horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(this, horizontalList);


    LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);

    horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
}
```

}

**Adapter**

```
    public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<String> horizontalList;
Context ctxt;


public HorizontalAdapter(Context context, List<String> horizontalList) {
    this.ctxt = context;
    this.horizontalList = horizontalList;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item_view, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.txtView.setText(horizontalList.get(position));

    holder.imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumbnail);

    holder.txtView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(ctxt, holder.txtView.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return horizontalList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtView;
    public ImageView imgView;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.video_title);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you want to play the video in another activity ? or in the cell ?

Comment: In another activity

Comment: get the absolute path of the clicked index video and pass it to next activity and play it using http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-video-streaming-videoview-tutorial/

Comment: Sorry to ask that I'm not able to understand...Can you be more clear or provide an example...

Answer (score 0):

```
Main Activity in --->>

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new Top_ServiceAdapter());

---->Adapter in you horizontal_item_view.xml layout in 

linearlayout in image or text  with orientation vertical .... so done this problem
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a class Item that contains: "title","videoUrl","thumbnail_url"

then your horizontal list would be a list of

```
private List<Item> horizontalList;
```

then on your viewHolder , you get the videoUrl and open the new activity with an intent that has the video url in its bundle.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctxt, VideoActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("VIDEO_URL", item.videoUrl);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and then on your VideoActivity you should implements an videoPlayer Library to show the video using the retrieved videoUrl

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String videoUrl = intent.getStringExtra("VIDEO_URL");
```